# Why is my Ada program not outputting correctly?

Tags: ada

Let me start by saying this is the first ada program I have ever created. I have no idea how it works, and my assignment is incredibly simple.  However, the output is not working correctly. It works with the first variable, but not with the next two. It also prints the first variable weird. Here is my code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
    Author, Title, Pages: String := " ";
begin

    Put("Enter Author: ");
    Get(Author);
    Put("Enter Title: ");
    Get(Title);
    Put("Enter number of pages: ");
    Get(Pages);
    Put("Author: ");
    Put(Author);
    New_Line;
    Put("Title: ");
    Put(Title);
    New_Line;
    Put("Number of pages: ");
    Put(Pages);

end Main;
```

The goal is simply to enter information about a book and the program reads it out to you.  This is the output:

```
Enter Author: john
Enter Title: Enter number of pages: Author: j
Title: o
Number of pages: h
```

Side note, I couldn't get page numbers to work as an integer.  The `get` and `put` methods just gave errors. That isn't important but if anyone can help make that an integer I would appreciate it.

Comment: The program does exactly what you've asked it to.  You may want to read up on how the type `String` is declared in Ada.  Reading the section on text I/O in the reference manual might also help.  Notice that there is a logical difference between `Get` and `Get_Line`.

Comment: Are you by any chance taking "CS 3304 - Data Structures"?

Comment: The type `String` in Ada has a specific property, i.e., the number of characters is exactly as given by the type. Your example initializes all the variables with the length of one (1) character. Thus, when you enter a 4 character string, it is _distributed_ among all the 4 string variables. If you want a variable length string, check `Ada.Unbounded_Strings` or `Ada.Fixed_Strings`. The former, as the name says, have no defined upper bound, whereas the latter allows you to specify it (in this case the string is up to the limit).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possible solution:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Text_Input is

   type Page_Count is range 1 .. 10_000;

   package Page_Count_Text_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO (Page_Count);

   function Get_Line (Message : in String) return String;
   function Get_Line (Message : in String) return Page_Count;

   function Get_Line (Message : in String) return String is
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put (Message);
      return Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line;
   end Get_Line;

   function Get_Line (Message : in String) return Page_Count is
   begin
      return Result : Page_Count do
         Ada.Text_IO.Put (Message);
         Page_Count_Text_IO.Get (Result);
         if Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line /= "" then
            raise Constraint_Error
              with "Page count followed by extra characters.";
         end if;
      end return;
   end Get_Line;

   Author : constant String     := Get_Line ("Enter author: ");
   Title  : constant String     := Get_Line ("Enter title: ");
   Pages  : constant Page_Count := Get_Line ("Enter number of pages: ");
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Author:          " & Author);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Title:           " & Title);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Number of pages:" & Page_Count'Image (Pages));
end Text_Input;
```

Notice that I've made the `Get_Line` function for `Page_Count` check that you don't have any trailing garbage on the line, where you enter the number of pages.

I hope you don't disagree with my estimate that John will never write a single book of more than 10'000 pages. :-)

Comment: The solution is also available as a part of my repository of Ada 2012 examples: https://bitbucket.org/sparre/ada-2012-examples/

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Jacob, I suspect you did this person's homework for him ("my assignment is incredibly simple") and he hasn't learned anything.

Comment: But if he hands it in, his professor will fail him, because it has been downloaded from the internet.